# Повтор кода после нажатия enter

Tags: c++

Не подскажете что нужно написать в простеньком коде, чтобы после выполнения функции он возвращался к началу?
То есть, грубо говоря, запускался заново.

Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    setlocale (0, "");

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;

    cout << "Введите числа х, y" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    cin >> y;

    z = x + y;
    cout <<"z = "<< z << endl;

    _getch();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: про циклы слышали?

Comment: На самом деле просто не пойму как им пользоваться в данном случае..
Поскольку цикл выполняется до принятия какого-то значения = не бесконечного.
То есть если я правильно понимаю после определенного рандомного выпадения числа, рано или поздно одна из переменных совпадет с значением переменной до которой цикл будет выполняться цикл (после чего он кончиться(если я правильно все понял)).

А интересует грубо говоря возвращение в начало кода....этакий return2begin)

Comment: @seawed: а вы про цикл `while` слышали? Почитайте, вам наверняка понравится.

Comment: не очень понял ваше объяснение..но сделаю вид, что все же понял. Наверное вы хотите что-то такое? 

    char p;
    while(p != 'q')
    {
        cin >> p;
        cout  << "\"" << p << "\" wasp pressed" << endl;
    }

Comment: Громко только не ругайтесь) но все равно не понимаю...
Нашел пример цикла while :
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    int i = 0; // инициализируем счетчик цикла.
    int sum = 0; // инициализируем счетчик суммы.
    while (i < 1000)
    {
        i++;
        sum += i;
    }
    cout << "Сумма чисел от 1 до 1000 = " << sum << endl; 
    return 0;
}

Если я правильно понял, цикл будет выполняться пока i(кол-во циклов) не будет 999. А мне нужно что-бы  все обнулялось и заново спрашивало. 
Если есть возможность пришлите код, наглядно проще понять.

Comment: вы просили не ругаться, но я все же немного ругнусь. Форматируйте пожалуйста код

Comment: @DreamChild: ставлю на то, что ТС хочет бесконечный цикл.

Comment: Да, именно)

мне нужно что бы каждый раз после выдачи ответов по решению, снова писалась фраза введите х и у....

И это количество не должно быть ограничено. Поскольку только начал учить С++ то многого не знаю, так что не судите строго)

Comment: @seawed: Вы бы сначала прочитали книжку по C++. Да, целую книжку. До конца. Любую. Нет, видеоуроки не годятся.

Потому что ваш вопрос уровня «как пишется буква A».

---
Для затравки подумайте, что будет с `while`-циклом в вашем примере, если вы не станете изменять переменную `i` внутри цикла. Или будете проверять не переменную `i`, а что-то другое.

Comment: Давайте проверим. Допустим если я введу переменную "K" и поставлю условие выполнение цикла если K = 0.... и по идее пока K = 0 цикл будет повторяться бесконечно... так?)
Попробовал следующее... #include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <conio.h> 

using namespace std;

int main ()
{ setlocale (0, "");


int x=0;
 int y=0;
  int z=0;
  int k=0;
  while (k=1);
  {
  
cout <<"ВВедите числа х, y"<< endl;
cin >> x;
cin >> y;
k=0;
z=x+y;
cout <<" z = "<< z  << endl;
  }

_getch();

return 0;
}
результатом стало черное окно...туплю наверное)

Comment: Просто while(1), и всё у вас будет ОК.

Comment: @seawed: Вы всё-таки возьмитесь за книгу. Потому что:

* В языке C++ проверка равенства обозначается как `==`, а не `=` (а `=` означает присваивание).
* Если вы поставили `;` после `while`, тем самым вы объявили тело цикла пустым — уберите точку с запятой.
* условия в `while` не обязательно проверяют числовую переменную, там может быть любое условие, любое выражение типа `bool`. В частности, константа.

Comment: google://c++ для чайников, там есть очень полезные результаты